# This endpoint does not support the `merchant` facade"

Tags: api, bitcoin, bitcoin-testnet

I have set up the bitpay API in PHP, I created a merchant token. for testing purpose, I have set up bitcoin core testnet wallet. But when I create payout to send bitcoin to my testnet wallet, I give me exception of "This endpoint does not support the `merchant` facade". My code for creating key,

```
    $storageEngine = new \Bitpay\Storage\EncryptedFilesystemStorage('mypassword');
    $privateKey = $storageEngine->load('bitpay.pri');
    $publicKey = $storageEngine->load('bitpay.pub');
    $client = new \Bitpay\Client\Client();
    $network = new \Bitpay\Network\Testnet();
    $adapter = new \Bitpay\Client\Adapter\CurlAdapter();
    $client->setPrivateKey($privateKey);
    $client->setPublicKey($publicKey);
    $client->setNetwork($network);
    $client->setAdapter($adapter);
    $sin = \Bitpay\SinKey::create()->setPublicKey($publicKey)->generate();
    try {
        $token = $client->createToken(
                array(
                    'facade' => 'merchant',
                    'label' => 'Demo',
                    'id' => (string) $sin,
                )
        );
        $pairingCode = $token->getPairingCode();
        $createdToken = $token->getToken();
        $this->ci->dashboard->addSettings('bit_token', $createdToken);
        echo $pairingCode;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $response;
    }
```

But when i crate a payout, then it gives me exception.

Answer (score -1):

I've dived into similar issue and it looks that to access Payouts API you have to use PAYROLL facade. You can find more info in the [docs](https://bitpay.com/api#resource-Payouts)